# Protect static files using jwt authentication

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, authorization, jwt

I'd like to protect [static files](http://expressjs.com/ru/starter/static-files.html) with JWT authentication. Is it possible to achieve without cookies? As I know the most common scenario for JWT is to pass token in request body or header, making AJAX call. But when browser requests static files (JS, CSS ... ), there is no way to add body to this request. So the only way is to store jwt token in cookie? Or there are others?

**Update**

> Did you have specific objections to a cookie?

Im reading articles, and everyone is passing jwt token in body or Authorization header. I develop website with admin panel - SPA application, so Im wondering, should I protect html, bundle.js, css of this panel with cookie or protect only API and make these files public. Just want to know what is the common flow. And I thought, maybe it's possible somehow, to protect these files with Authorization header (like Basic Auth) but using JWT

Comment: You could always add the JWT to the query parameters: i.e. append something like `?jwt=...` to all the URLs that reference a static file.

Comment: @DarkFalcon, yep, but it's hard to add this token to each request manually, but as an option)

Comment: Of course, but that's pretty much your only alternative to a cookie. Did you have specific objections to a cookie?

Comment: @DarkFalcon, Im reading articles, and everyone is passing jwt token in body or Authorization header. I develop website with admin panel - SPA application, so Im wondering, should I protect html, bundle.js, css of this panel with cookies or protect only API and make these files public. Just want to know what is the common flow. And I thought, maybe it's possible somehow, to protect these files with Authorization header (like Basic Auth) but using JWT.

Comment: @asv - I've been banging my head against a wall for days with same problem. I must secure images due to partner contracts. 

Maybe its my setup, which is:
express server -> `express.static` -> react app.
user submits login -> react sends (axios) post request to a login route in express; passing the users name/password -> express sends `request` to JWT service (AuthO) -> express responds to the post request with jwt token -> react saves token in localStorage.

I have another route for images but I can't see how to add jwt mid ware to that request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I have a binary file (static file) to be protected this manner. Can I host this static file in Webserver and access it with the JWT in query param ? What happens if user tries to hit the file URL without the JWT query param ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most often it is unnecessary to protect static assets (e.g. `.html`, `.css`, `.png`, `.js`, etc.) files and protecting your API endpoints would suffice.

However, if you retrieve the assets (e.g. HTML fragments for an SPA) using AJAX, then you can pass the JWT as a header inside your request and in the backend your web server can inspect the header and return the HTML fragment only if the current user is authorized to access it.

Also you can store the JWT inside [local storage](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/) and configure your AJAX library to get the token from the local storage and add it to your requests before sending them to the server.

Comment: I have a binary (static file) to be protected this manner. Can I host this static file in Webserver and access it with the JWT ? In such case, what happens if user tries to hit the file URL without the JWT ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what questions you exactly means, but I think you want to protect specify static files like personal images or some else.

If like my think, you can `.use(jwt)` to protect your specify static files before `.use(static)` files.

for example:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const exjwt = require("express-jwt");
const STATIC_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), "src", "static");

app
  .use("/images", exjwt({ secret: "SECRET" }))
  .use(express.static(STATIC_PATH))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('...') 
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Like this, user can request your static files except static images files.